# Need proper demo for face detection using opencv

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection

Hello is there anybody who can help me with the opencv face detection with latest library for android. I already tried many demo from github but i got issues like library libtbt.so not found and app gets crash. If anyone has proper solution please send me link or demo that can run without error or any tutorial that I can follow.

I want for android, i have windows 7 and android studio latest version.

It is my first question so if anythig missing pardon for that
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show code. Please read this forums help section about what is a good questions andhow to ask one. This forum is not for general recommendations or to show you how to do something from scratch. If you want that, then search the forum or search Google for examples.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i'll attach a list of links to tutorials and videos i used to develop my opencv face recognition tool, in terms of your problem i think you're missing a key framework, if you follow the link i provided it should work let me know if it does. I know you wanted a demo but the best way to learn this is to follow one of the tutorials i provided.

**how to install for mac** : https://medium.com/@nuwanprabhath/installing-opencv-in-macos-high-sierra-for-python-3-89c79f0a246a

**Tutorials** :

https://opencv-python tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_atutorials.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY9f-6u2Q_c

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/19/opencv-tutorial-a-guide-to-learn-opencv/

Comment: Hello Gal Zahavi it is for android? Sorry i didn't mentioned that i will edit my question. I need for android. Thank you for the help